# How do I guarantee that the extrema found using Lagrange Multipliers are in fact max or min?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I've been looking at the forum and [this particular question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736681/how-do-i-classify-extrema-found-using-lagrange-multipliers) **almost** answered what I would want to know. The question, nevertheless, is a little different from what I would like to ask.

I'm given a simple Lagrange Multiplier problem:

> Miminize $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ given the constraint $x+y+z = 1$

(Larson 10th edition)

My answer (checked on the end of the book) was

> $x = y = z = \frac{1}{3} \qquad f\left( \frac{1}{3} , \frac{1}{3} , \frac{1}{3} \right) = \frac{1}{3}$

But the real question (at least to me) is: how do I guarantee that it is in fact a minimum?

Should I

**1. Use intuition**

**2. Use a hessian matrix (is this case, how exactly for this example)?**

Also:

**3. Why do books do not mention this (predictable) question?**

Thank you.

Comment: 1. No. 2. For example. 3. You need to ask the author. If I have to guess, the book has discussed convex problems before and has shown / stated that for convex problems the Lagrange multiplier method is sufficient (assuming the problem satisfies some constraint qualification).

Comment: The answer I gave in the post you linked *does* give the correct method to do a Hessian test with Lagrange multipliers. And there are textbooks (e.g., Marsden and Tromba and my own) that do give (and prove in an exercise?) the result. But this question is considered too challenging for a standard calculus student to be concerned with. As Martin said, you have your list of candidate points and intuition tells you the function must have a minimum (far from a proof, but intuitively, as you go "to infinity" on the constraint plane, the function $f$ goes to infinity).

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange Multiplier algorithm will give you **all** the critical points. So, if there is a minimum, it will be in your list and it will be the one(s) that produces the smallest value of $f$.

So the only relevant question is whether a minimum exists at all. And, in this case and many you know a minimum exists because you can restrict the domain so that it is compact and at least one of the coordinates is greater than one (say)
 in absolute value (for example the set of those $x,y,z$ with $x+y+z=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 3$). As the function $f$ is continuous and applies to a compact set, it achieves its max and its min.

Note, though, that in order to apply the above you need to consider the edges of the domain as critical points. For instance, treating your example as I mention above the equations that Lagrange Multipliers give you will not express the maximum, because it occurs on the edge (somewhere on the circle).

As Ted Shifrin mentioned, this goes beyond the typical Several Variables course.

Comment: There's no constraint here (at least stated in the problem) that $x,y,z\ge 0$, and so the domain is the entire plane $x+y+z=1$. However, we could easily by symmetry reduce to the case where all the variables are nonnegative; that has the disadvantage of boundary edges and vertices, which we now have to check separately. But there are additional ways to make a compactness argument (for example, restricting ourselves to the points in the plane where $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 6$). This is beyond the scope of a standard multivariable calculus course, however.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.