# Prove formally that multivariate function has global extrema

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider the following function: $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = p_1 \log x_1 + \dots + p_n\log x_n$ subject to the constraint that $\sum_i p_i = \sum_i x_i = 1$. It is also known that $p_i \in [0,1]$ and $x_i \in [0,1]$.

I need to prove formally that the function has global maximum when $\frac{p_1}{x_1} = \dots = \frac{p_n}{x_n}$, i.e, $x_i = p_i$ gives the global maximum.

I can prove this formally for two variables by using the standard first and second derivative test (eliminate one of the variables). I can also verify empirically that $x_i = p_i$ is the global maximum of this function when $n > 2$ but want to prove this formally.

Is there a suitable technique for multivariate functions that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Lagrange multipliers method we obtain $$\nabla f=(\dfrac{p_1}{x_1},\cdots ,\dfrac{p_n}{x_n})=\lambda_1(1,1,\cdots,1)$$which means that $$\dfrac{p_1}{x_1}=\cdots =\dfrac{p_n}{x_n}=\lambda_1$$To complete our proof we need to show that the hessian is negative definite at this point. We have $$H=\begin{bmatrix}-\dfrac{p_1}{x_1^2}&0&\cdots&0\\0&-\dfrac{p_2}{x_2^2}&\cdots&0\\.\\.\\.\\0&0&\cdots&-\dfrac{p_n}{x_n^2}\end{bmatrix}$$which is negative definite (semi-definite) since $p>0$ ($p\ge 0$)

Comment: This is a critical point and not necessarily the global maximum. How can I reason formally that this is indeed the global maximum?

Comment: This because the hessian matrix is negative definite . I will add this argument later to my answer

Comment: Excellent! Hessian matrix argument makes sense. Please add the argument for completeness and I can then accept this answer!

Comment: Sure! I'm working on it....

Comment: Your comment was good. Also i had a flaw in my proof. I treated to the $p_i$s as if they are variables (rather than constants). Hope it helps now!

Comment: Does Lagranges multiplier method give all critical points? Hessian matrix argument only says that if it is negative definite, a local maximum occurs. But in order to show that global maximum also occurs, we need to be sure that this is the only critical point (or the best critical point). My function is convex so I guess that is straightforward to argue. Do you agree?

Comment: That's right. In fact in a convex optimization (where the function and the constraints are all convex) the LMM gives us all the maxima and minima (as a very special case of K.K.T method) but generally in any point with gradient and hessian being zero and positive (negative) definite respectively, the point is a local minima (maxima). You can consider the following Taylor series for this $$f(x+d)=f(x)+d^T\nabla f+\dfrac{1}{2}d^THd+o(||d||^2)$$where $d$ is some arbitrary vector

Comment: This hessian does not work when you have a constraint. See my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736681/how-do-i-classify-extrema-found-using-lagrange-multipliers/1736696#1736696) for an explanation of a correct approach. ... By the way, here a compactness argument should establish you have a global maximum, so a local max/min test isn't required.

Comment: I couldn't add all of those information here for sake of brevity. In fact a point is a local minima if $f(x+d)\ge f(x)$ for any feasible direction $d$ ($d\in\Omega_x$) but when your hessian matrix is always definite (whether positive, negative , etc.) regardless the constraints we always have extrema. In our case the hessian matrix is always positive semi-definite therefore the local maximum is also global.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Using a Lagrangian multiplier,

$$f(x_i;\lambda)=\sum p_i\log x_i+\lambda\left(1-\sum x_i\right).$$

An extremum is achieved when

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x_i;\lambda)=\frac{p_i}{x_i}-\lambda=0,\\\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}f(x_i;\lambda)=1-\sum x_i=0.$$

After elimination of the $x_i$,

$$1-\frac1\lambda\sum p_i=0$$ gives $\lambda$.

---

Now we have to consider the cases such that one or more variable saturates. If saturation occurs towards $0$, then the term $\log x_i$ goes to minus infinity and cannot achieve a maximum. If saturation is towards $1$, the term $p_i\log x_i$ vanishes. Solving the reduced problem, we have

$$\lambda=\sum_{i\notin S}p_i,$$ $$x_i=\frac{p_i}\lambda$$ and the objective function equals

$$\sum_{i\ne S}p_i\log x_i=\sum_{i\ne S}(p_i\log p_i-p_i\log \lambda).$$

Comment: So I did that but this method only gives critical points (which may or may not be global maximum or minimum). How can I ensure that this point is indeed the global maximum?

Comment: Nice! This is a great proof as well. Thank you!